# Slick carousel not assigning proper width to elements

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I have the following js code in a loop

```
$(".team-scroller .teams").append("<div class='team-panel'>" +
                                "<div class='team-text'>" + first_team + "</div>" +
                                "<div class='team-text'>VS</div>" +
                                "<div class='team-text'>" + second_team +"</div>" +
                                "<div class='row'>" +
                                  "<div class='colmn-5'>" +
                                    "<div class='mdate'>" + day + " " + month + "</div>" +
                                  "</div>" +
                                  "<div class='colmn-5' style='float:right;'>" +
                                    "<a class='buy-tickets-btn' href='" + book_link + "'>Buy Tickets</a>" +
                                  "</div>" +
                              "</div>")
```

where `<div class="team-scroller teams"></div>` is the parent element and it has several `<div class="team-panel"></div>` as children. Following is the initialization code for slick

```
$('.team-scroller .teams').slick({
        infinite: false,
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 4,
        arrows: true,
        prevArrow: '<div class="left-dir"><span class="ic-arlt rgarr"></span></div>',
        nextArrow: '<div class="right-dir"><span class="ic-arrt rgarr"></span></div>',
        responsive: [
          {
            breakpoint: 1024,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 3,
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 600,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 2,
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 1,
            }
          }
        ]
      });
```

The problem is - I see 4 elements and the starting half of the fifth element in every scroll, instead of just 4 elements in each scroll. In other words, the width of the child elements is not being assigned properly by slick.
**How can I get slick to assign proper widths to the child elements?**

Comment: can you please add fiddle? or you code loop ?

Comment: if this (<div class="team-scroller teams"></div>) is your dom structure. You have to use $('.team-scroller.teams'). There should not be any spaces.

Comment: here's a codepen link [link](http://codepen.io/blackblood/pen/ZYwwgE)..although its working fine there